# Dialogflow: How to create intents with specific context input by code?

Tags: input, dialogflow-es

My question is about using code to generate all dialogflow intents automatically.
I'm preparing my Intents on a GoogleSheet and I want to be able to export this sheet and generate my Dialogflow intents from this sheet automatically.
I'm writing an application in C# to achieve this, but, sadly, it seems that it is not possible to set context input when I create a new intent. (InputContextNames)
It seems strange for me and I would like to know if there is not any way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got it! You have to instantiate a Context first and then add its ContextName to the InputsContextNames of your intent!